# UINavigationController subclass with custom back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I know I can set custom back button from the view controller itself, something like:

```
- (void)setBackButton
{
    UINavigationBar* navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIButton* backButton = [navBar backButtonWith:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackButton.png"] 
                                        highlight:nil 
                                     leftCapWidth:14.0];

    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
}

- (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that I need to do it for all my view controllers...
One solution is to put this code in some BasicViewController and all my view controllers will subclass it.

**But my question is can I subclass the UINavigationCotroller itself and set it's nab bar left button to this custom button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is using [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

It provides methods on `UIBarButtonItem` such as

`- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`

and

`- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:(CGFloat)adjustment forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics`

Comment: Yes, why are you still supporting anything less?

Comment: There is zero support for styling the back button in < iOS5, setting a left button has subtle behavior differences

Comment: which behavior differences do you mean? and what do you think I should do if I support iOS 4?

Comment: Animation differences, left bar button items will slide with the nav, back items stay in place.

Comment: Ya u r right I didn't noticed it until now.. What do u think I should do here? Should I check the device version and use UIAppearance if iOS 5, or should I anyway use my current implementation with a BasicViewController and custom back button?

Answer (score 1):

No. It would be better to have a custom UIViewController that handles this behavior.